# Sun/Oracle & IBM JCEKS keystore incompatibility

Tags: java, keystore, sun

I've been running a server on the OpenJDK. I now have a new version of the server but this one is running on IBM Java. I need to give an encryption key, stored in a JCEKS keystore, from the old server to the new one.

Frustratingly I have learned that the keystores are incompatible between the two JRE vendors. Is it possible to convert a Sun/Oracle JCEKS keystore to its IBM equivalent? Or can I somehow pull the secret key from the Sun/Oracle keystore and use it to create an IBM one from scratch?

Comment: Short answer: you can probably "export" everything you need from your old keystore and "import" it into your new keystore.  Who knows - you might even be able to "share" keystores (if the new web server happens to support JCEKS)..  Q:What is your "server"?  IBM WebSphere?  Useful link: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/csec_sslkeystoreconfs.html

Answer (score 1):

It is a well documented issue, that if you use IBM’s keytool to create PKCS12 (an RSA standard) keystores, they cannot be opened by Oracle’s keytool unless you use the non-portable (IBM specific) PKCS12S2 store  type:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.70.doc/security-component/keytoolDocs/supportedkeystoretypes.html

Answer (score 0):

JCEKS and JKS are different userstore types, nothing to do with IBM. Until you specify the userstore type and the JRE understands it you should be ok. If you have any option to do so.

You can you the default keytool command to migrate the keypairs (with the importkeystore parameter), just specify the source and destination  store type.
If you can use UI (windows, X Windows) you can use an open source project called "keystore-explorer".

Have fun

Gabriel

Comment: I did not mention anything about JKS; both keystores are JCEKS type

Comment: We had no problems to migrate between the runtimes. The keystores should be compatible. Just an idea  - couldn't be a problem with the JCE Unlimited strength policy? (for keys of 2048 bit or longer)

Comment: Seems you are right, we've migrated through pkcs12... it worked in both providers.. But indeed - strange :/